# What Quantifier is Used When Assuming P(n) for some n, in the Induction Hypothesis?

Tags: induction, quantifiers

In the induction step, we (usually) want to prove that

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, P(n) \implies P(n+1)$$

so we assume $P(n)$ for "some" natural $n$, and show that it implies $P(n+1)$.

My question of this: what sort of quantifier are we applying to $n$ when we say, "For some $n$"?

Initially, It seems like it is just the existential quantifier, since $\exists$ is often translated to "for some."

But this doesn't seem to make much sense in the context of an induction hypothesis, because the "some" $n$ for which $P(n)$ is true could very well not include the base case.

It also couldn't be that "some" here means "for all," since that begs the question.

Instead of just "some," I have also seen the word "arbitrary" used, as in "Assume $P(n)$ for some arbitrary $n$," and this seems to make more sense to me. It feels like we are not taking any particular $n$, nor every $n$, but just something that represents $n$ in an abstract way and using that to prove the implication.

But I would be interested to hear a proper explanation of this.

Comment: We do not assume $P(n)$ just for "some" $n$, but for arbitrary given $n$, and then conclude $P(n+1)$. So it is as you said.

Comment: And since $n$ is arbitrary, it can be any $n$, so it needs to apply to all $n$; we are still assuming the universal quantifier.

Comment: "any" rather than "some".

Comment: The "logic" is : assume $P(n)$ for $n$ **whatever** and prove - on this assumption - that $P(n+1)$ holds. Then, apply [Conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) to conclude that $P(n) \to P(n+1)$ holds (without assumptions).

Comment: Finally, apply [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to conclude with $\forall n (P(n) \to P(n+1))$. Universal generalization formalizes exactly the intuitive argument that if some "facts" holds for an object whatever, it must hold for **every** object.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that an expression in a subproof can be interpreted as a fully quantified statement.  It is just the way some FOLs work.  People think that deductive logics always take fully meaningful statements and infer new fully meaningful statements from them, but not many (formal) logics actually work like that.

Answer (score 1):

> In the induction step, we (usually) want to prove that
>
> $$\forall n{\in} \mathbb{N},\; P(n) \implies P(n+1)$$

This is correct. (But $(1)$ below is clearer.)

> so we assume $P(n)$ for "some" natural $n$, and show that it implies
> $P(n+1)$.
>
> My question of this: what sort of quantifier are we applying to $n$
> when we say, "For some $n$"?

I've seen authors write this too; here's an excerpt (emphasis mine):

- For the induction step, suppose that $P(k)$ is true for **some** natural number $k;$ we want to show that $P(k+1)$ is true.

So, this mistake isn't uncommon, and yes, it is a mistake: what we are supposing, rather, is that $P(k)$ is true for **an arbitrary** natural number $k,$ so that we can conclude (implicitly invoking [Universal Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization)) at the end of this section that $$\forall k{\in} \mathbb{N}\; \Big(P(k) \implies P(k+1)\Big).\tag1$$

> Instead of just "some," I have also seen the word "arbitrary" used, as
> in "Assume $P(n)$ for some arbitrary $n$," and this seems to make more
> sense to me.

Yes indeed. However, to more clearly distinguish this from existential quantification, I'd write "for an arbitrary $n$" instead of "for some arbitrary $n$".